# How do I setup an AngularJS app with onDeviceReady and initialize functions for Cordova?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on my first Cordova app to use AngularJS and I'm a bit lost as to how to coalesce the starting JS for a Cordova project.

I presently have the default index.js file that is included with Cordova that I've modified to include some events based on when the device goes on or offline. It creates an object (app) and adds functions for initialize, bindEvents, and onDeviceready.

Where should I define the AngularJS application? After the app.initialize() function call at the bottom of the document? Or can I ditch the original Cordova structure for the JS file entirely and do something else for the onDeviceReady?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can define angular anywhere, I recommend a separate file.
The thing you have to worry about is angular being loaded first before cordova.
Below is an example how to overcome this using a service.

```
.service('cordovaReady', function($q){
 var cordovaDefer = $q.defer();

 //Note: if you want browser support you'll need to detect
 //what platform you're running because deviceready event won't be called
 //unless cordova is running.
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", cordovaDefer.resolve, false);

 return function(){
  return cordovaDefer.promise;
 };
});
```

And using it every time you use a cordova plugin in your app like so:

```
//$cordovaFacebook is just an example
.controller('someCtrl', function(cordovaReady, $cordovaFacebook){
 cordovaReady()
  .then(function(){

   //Plugins available here
   $cordovaFacebook.api('/me').then(...);
});
```